# Fill rmultiple ows in between pandas dataframe rows on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where I have date wise withdraw/credit and closing balance information.

```
date      withdraw     credit    closing_balance
02/06/17    2,500.00      nan           6,396.77
03/06/17      nan      36,767.00       43,163.77
05/06/17    1,770.00      nan          41,393.77
05/06/17     6000.00      nan           35393.77
05/06/17      278.00      nan           35115.77
07/06/17     1812.00      nan           33303.77
```

Now we can see that we have 2 days entries missing in this table.
i.e **04/06/17 and 06/06/17**. Since there were no transactions on that day.

What I'm looking to do is add dummy rows in the dataframe for these dates, 4th and 6th, with

withdraw column as **0**, credit column as **0**,

And closing balance column as the same of the last closing balance entry of the previous day.

Expected output

```
date      withdraw     credit    closing_balance
02/06/17    2,500.00      nan           6,396.77
03/06/17      nan      36,767.00       43,163.77
04/06/17     nan(or 0)  nan(or 0)      43,163.77
05/06/17    1,770.00      nan          41,393.77
05/06/17     6000.00      nan           35393.77
05/06/17      278.00      nan           35115.77
06/06/17    nan(or 0)   nan(or 0)       35115.77
07/06/17     1812.00      nan           33303.77
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing this.

What i thought was to first find the missing dates, then create a ttemporary dataframe for those dates and then concatenate it with the main dataframe and then sort.

But I'm having issue in how to get the previous days last closing balance entry, to fill in the missing days closing balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is add all missing datetimes with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) and left join by another `DataFrame` created with minimal and maximal datetimes and [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Then forward filling missing values for `closing_balance` and set `0` for new datetimes:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max())})

df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left')
df2['closing_balance'] = df2['closing_balance'].ffill()
df2.loc[~df2['Date'].isin(df['Date']), ['withdraw','credit']] = 0
print (df2)
        Date  withdraw     credit closing_balance
0 2017-06-02  2,500.00        NaN        6,396.77
1 2017-06-03       NaN  36,767.00       43,163.77
2 2017-06-04         0          0       43,163.77
3 2017-06-05  1,770.00        NaN       41,393.77
4 2017-06-05   6000.00        NaN        35393.77
5 2017-06-05    278.00        NaN        35115.77
6 2017-06-06         0          0        35115.77
7 2017-06-07   1812.00        NaN        33303.77
```

Similar idea with different condition for set `0` values with `merge` and `indicator` parameter:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(df['Date'].min(), df['Date'].max())})

df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left', indicator=True)
df2['closing_balance'] = df2['closing_balance'].ffill()
df2.loc[df2.pop('_merge').eq('left_only'), ['withdraw','credit']] = 0
print (df2)
        Date  withdraw     credit closing_balance
0 2017-06-02  2,500.00        NaN        6,396.77
1 2017-06-03       NaN  36,767.00       43,163.77
2 2017-06-04         0          0       43,163.77
3 2017-06-05  1,770.00        NaN       41,393.77
4 2017-06-05   6000.00        NaN        35393.77
5 2017-06-05    278.00        NaN        35115.77
6 2017-06-06         0          0        35115.77
7 2017-06-07   1812.00        NaN        33303.77
```